# Eclipse cross platform method to get git rev into version.h

Tags: linux, windows, eclipse, platform

I am using eclipse indigo (can't update to newer versions since this indigo is wrapped in vendor environment). I place the git commit hash into a version.h file using a pre build step to run a (crappy) batch file (hey I'll admit to being a script kitty who cobbles stuff together to get the job done):

```
rem echo off
git rev-parse HEAD >> commithash
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set "line=" 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (commithash) do set "line=!line!%%a" 
echo char * version=^"%line%^"; > ..\Application\version.h
del commithash
```

The result is this:
char * version="e016e6df4f17e7fd982d9a2575d8410eadf3c4b2";

Now I need to take this same project and compile it on linux.
Even though there are ways to run the same script on windows and linux, I am certain that I've made it way worse than it needs to be. I am sure there is a way to use a makefile (I am using managed makefiles) to do exactly this but I can't find out where to get documentation that explains the (entire) make system of eclipse so I can truly understand. I've tried doing this by adding a builder but that doesn't work and again I can't find out where to get documentation that explains the (entire) "builder" system of eclipse so I can truly understand. So, my three-pronged question is:

1) Where can I get something that explains how the indigo eclipse make system works AND the builder system works (and I don't want the eclipse documentation that tells what button to click to open the builder dialog and how to enter text into the fields and what button to click to close the dialog). I want to understand what is happening and how it works.

2) If the resource in (1) does not exist, how do I setup a builder that actually works (I've tried and searched and experimented and wasted too much of the customer's dollars) to do this?

3) If neither (1) or (2) are possible, how can I create a makefile (step?) that will do this cross platform?

Deep appreciation in advance. I could even send cash if required.

Comment: Are we allowed to accept tips on SO?  lol - well written question, good luck!

Comment: Money is never required here! Once you receive an answer, if you wish to express your appreciation you can upvote it and mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: How do you run the batch script on Windows and what is the problem with migrating to Linux? Why can't you update?

Comment: howlger: I run the batch on windows using a pre-build step. You made me think about why it can't be run on linux. I think the primary problem is paths...But now I have to check. Will update with that answer. Thanks for questioning me.

Comment: howlger: It runs on linux just fine after I resolved path questions. Thanks again for asking!